# ITIN Application- IRS requested to submit original passport

Tags: irs, itin

We have submitted my spouse passport on June 16 for ITIN application and received ITIN number on August 23 but still did not receive original passport back.

We try to contact IRS multiple times but no luck. They keep on asking us to wait and sharing that they don't have any information.

Please share any suggestions or how we can expedite to track them for any info.

Comment: You can always apply for a replacement passport from your country of nationality on the basis that it's lost.

Comment: Reporting a passport lost can carry some unpleasant issues and extra work, if the process in the U.S. is any indication, it is always better to recover the original than to report it lost. My two cents.

Comment: You might ask your employer if they could contact their local congressperson's office to look into it.